# Is there a way to have the for loop take an array and compute its average?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have the following code and the logic seems to be correct. However, when I run the last console.log   ( 'console.log(bills)'), nothing shows up for its output.

```js
const bills = [22, 295, 176, 440, 37, 105, 10, 1100, 86, 52]

const tipsTotal = [];
let sum = 0;

const calcTip = function(bill) {
  return bill >= 50 && bill <= 300 ? bill * .15 : bill * .20;
}


for (let i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
  const value = calcTip(bills[i]);
  calcTip(tipsTotal.push(value));
}

console.log(tipsTotal);

const calcAverage = function(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; arr.length; i++) {

    sum = sum + arr[i];
  }

  let average = sum / arr.length;
  return average;
}

console.log(calcAverage(bills));
```

Comment: oh, I see ... `arr.length;` always truthy, so your code is an infinite loop - try `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)`

Comment: `for (let i = 0; arr.length; i++)` --> The condition `arr.length` is truthy and always will be. You created an infinite loop, preventing the code from going any further.

Comment: It doesn’t give any output on google chrome when I use ‘console.log(bills)’. Wait, I think I didn’t specific the type for ‘art’. It’s suppose to be an array but it only has ‘art’ as parameter for ‘calcAverage’.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `sum` variable should be declared inside `calcAverage`.
2. You forgot to check if the loop index reached the end of the array: `i < arr.length`

```js
const bills = [22, 295, 176, 440, 37, 105, 10, 1100, 86, 52];

const tipsTotal = [];

const calcTip = function(bill) {
  return bill >= 50 && bill <= 300 ? bill * .15 : bill * .20;
}


for (let i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
  const value = calcTip(bills[i]);
  calcTip(tipsTotal.push(value));
}

console.log(tipsTotal);

const calcAverage = function(arr) {
  let sum = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    sum = sum + arr[i];
  }

  let average = sum / arr.length;
  return average;
}

console.log(calcAverage(bills));
```

Comment: 1. should be, but doesn't have to be

Comment: it works now. apparently, defining sum as global or local, works in either case.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce works great in these cases

```js
const bills = [22, 295, 176, 440, 37, 105, 10, 1100, 86, 52];
const sum = bills.reduce((sum,bill) => {
  const tip = bill >= 50 && bill <= 300 ? bill * .15 : bill * .20;
  sum += (bill+tip);
  return sum;
},0)

console.log(sum.toFixed(2),(sum/bills.length).toFixed(2));
```